# awstats mail log analyser

Tags: centos5, awstats

i have configured mail log analyser(awstats) on my mail server,but i am not getting reports of users who send or receive mail from my mail server,i want a cron job to automaticaly update the mail logs when a user send or receive mail,what can i do to achieve this.

My mail server configuration is as following:-

> centOs 5,postfix server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The awstats documentation was plenty detailed for me.

In short: post-process the log files with the provided postfix-specific (!) script, then load up as usual, optionally excluding or tuning certain output tables and graphs.

Comment: Sh*t no, learning how to configure a web server is an entirely separate and quite complex topic all on its own.